# Python: convert array of uint16_t to string (from Arduino over RS-485)

Tags: python, arduino, modbus, uint16, minimalmodbus

I'm trying to send json over modbus rtu (I know, it is very bad use of modbus.)

My schema is similar to:
[image]

I have connected Arduino USB to PC as COM5 and RS485 converter connected to USB-RS485 to PC as COM4.

[image]

If I read data from Arduino using [QModBus](http://qmodbus.sourceforge.net/) application, I will see a lot 
 of bytes (COM4).

For control: after I send from QModBus "read holding registers" Arduino serial monitor on "Arduino usb port" (COM5) print valid string. So I mean that modbus bytes are ok:

[image]

There is my Arduino code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ModbusRtu.h>
#define ID   1

// assign the Arduino pin that must be connected to RE-DE RS485 transceiver
#define TXEN  2 

Modbus slave(ID, 0, TXEN); // this is slave ID and RS-232 or USB-FTDI

// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[100];

boolean state;
String json = "{\"idx\":1430,\"nvalue\":0,\"svalue\":\"-58.00\"}";

void setup() {
  slave.begin( 9600 );
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;  
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json); 
}

void loop() {
  // https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/blob/master/ModbusRtu.h#L1391
  byte x = 0;
  for (byte i = 0; i < json.length(); i += 2) {
    uint16_t temp;
    temp = word(
      json[i],
      json[i+1]);  
    au16data[x] = temp;
    x++;
  }

  state = slave.poll( au16data, 100 );  
}
```

But I don't know how to convert these bytes back to json string in python. My code:

```
import serial
import minimalmodbus

MODBUS_3  = 3  # Read holding registers

dev1 = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM4', 1)  # port name, slave address (in decimal)
dev1.serial.baudrate = 9600
dev1.serial.bytesize = 8
dev1.serial.stopbits = 1
dev1.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
dev1.debug = False

data = dev1.read_registers(0, 20, MODBUS_3)
print(data)
```

Code print my the same values as QModBus:

```
[31522, 26980, 30754, 14897, 13363, 12332, 8814, 30305, 27765, 25890, 14896, 11298, 29558, 24940, 30053, 8762, 8749, 13624, 11824, 12322]
```

Can you please help, how can I convert these numbers to json string as you can see in arduino serial monitor?

And how to convert python string to "uint_16t" for sending over modbus.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import struct
dataStr = b''
for uint_16t in data:
    dataStr += struct.pack('>I', uint_16t)
print dataStr
```

Output based on your supplied list:

```
  {"idx":1430,"nvalue":0,"svalue":"-58.00"
```

Not sure why it is missing the closing } though...

Edit:  To remove that weird whitespace you can do:

```
for i in dataStr:
    if ord(i) != 0:
        newDataStr += i
print newDataStr
```

Comment: Can you please help what data type should I used? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a23721d58a654f528b4f2bea77f6de3a
I'm using Python 3.6.4.

Comment: Maybe try: dataStr += struct.pack('>I', int(str(uint_16t)))

Comment: No, it not works :-(

dataStr += struct.pack('>I', int(str(uint_16t)))

TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: I modified python code (add `b'`) and now it almost works. But in string ouput there are a lot of spaces. Where are they from? And how can I remove it? It looks like uint16 char space uint16 ...
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ea74355f1244359e7ee0f19abc8509a

Comment: I updated my answer.  If it works for you, please accept it :)

Comment: Thank you! A do a little change and now it works!
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cce3a2ba34f4242a2f9e9a4bfdd6d2c5